# How to loop through Map in Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am trying to understand how to loop through all entries in a Map in Thymeleaf.  I have a domain object being processed by Thymeleaf that contains a Map.

How do I loop through the keys and fetch the values ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Nevermind... I found it...

```
<tr th:each="instance : ${analysis.instanceMap}">
    <td th:text="${instance.key}">keyvalue</td>
    <td th:text="${instance.value.numOfData}">num</td>
</tr>
```

Thanks.

Comment: What was the source for this?

Comment: ["When iterating maps, iter variables will be of class java.util.Map.Entry."](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#iterable-values)

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a way to do this for any object under Java 8 or 9? Just like iterating over objects in JavaScript and JSON, I would think there be a way to take a serializable object of type Foo and do <tr> <th:block><div th:each="field : ${someFoo}"><th th:text="${field.name}"> </th></div></th:block>

If this can't be done, can this become part of Java 10 or the next major version of thymeleaf? This would solve so many headaches and reduce a lot of performance overhead turning entity objects into maps before running them through template engines.

Answer (score 57):

In case you have a List as the value. For example, when you have a map with key being the category, and value being a list of items pertaining to that category, you can use this:

```
<table>
    <tr th:each="element : ${catsAndItems}">
        <td th:text="${element.key}">keyvalue</td>
        <table>
            <tr th:each="anews : ${element.value}">
                <td th:text="${anews.title}">Some name</td>
                <td th:text="${anews.description}">Some name</td>
                <td th:text="${anews.url}">Some name</td>
                <td th:text="${anews.logo}">Some name</td>
                <td th:text="${anews.collectionDate}">Some name</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </tr>
</table>
```