# How to fix issue sending hashmap to Thyemleaf?

Tags: javascript, java, thymeleaf

I am building a project that has values in a Java `HashMap` and I would like to place it into my front-end Thymeleaf. Though I looked up some code on their Documentation and Stack Overflow, I can't seem to find a good answer to my question. I have some code below that does not pass the values and I am wondering where I made the mistake at.

So for all the keys, I am trying to make them a `optgroup`. For the values, I want to make it a `option`. Any help would be appreciated.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
                            <div class="col col-lg-9 search-bar">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Type:</label> 
                                    <select class="js-example-basic-single2" id="selectData2">

                                        <optgroup th:each="tierList : ${hmap}"
                                              th:label="${tierList.key}">
                                            <option th:each=" system : ${tierList.value}"
                                                th:value="${system}"
                                                th:selected="${system}"
                                                th:text="${system}">
                                            </option>
                                        </optgroup>
                                    </select>


                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: First thing to note is that you're trying to reuse the name `hmap`. Once you fix that, you are looking for `item.name` and `item.key`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23144358/how-to-loop-through-map-in-thymeleaf

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- So I made an edit to my code to add the fixes you stated, however it is still not working. Not sure where, I messed up

Comment: Did you see the second half of my comment or the link?

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- Thanks but It turns out it was a Java related question, I solved it by adding ```modelAndView.addObject("hmap",hmap);``` I originally forgot to tell the object what to name the ```Map``` when it gets passed. Thanks anyways though