# How to print out elements from the List grouped by alphabet letters in Thymeleaf?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have the following db table:

```
CREATE TABLE authors
    (
        id         INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        authorName VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL
    );
```

I want to print our the authors as follows:

A

- Anselma McKennan

B

- Berty Gandley
- Bette-ann Askem

C

- Clerc Djakovic
- Cristie Isacsson

D

- Dannie Glidder
- Darcey Rohmer
- Dom Robuchon

Currently I have by thymleaf template printing as follows and I do not want to print out the Alphabet LETTER each time in front of the author:

A

- Anselma McKennan

B

- Berty Gandley

B

- Bette-ann Askem

C

- Clerc Djakovic

C

- Cristie Isacsson

D

- Dannie Glidder

D

- Darcey Rohmer

D

- Dom Robuchon

My controller:

```
@GetMapping("/index.html")
    public String mainPage(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("authorsData", bookService.getAuthorData());
        return "/authors/index";
    }
```

My service:

```
public List<Author> getAuthorData() {
    List<Author> authors = jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT id, authorName from authors ORDER BY authorName", (ResultSet rs, int rowNum) -> {
        Author author = new Author();
        author.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
        author.setAuthorName(rs.getString("authorName"));
        return author;
    });
    return new ArrayList<>(authors);
}
```

My Thymeleaf code is as follows:

```
<div class="Authors-block" th:each="author : ${authorsData}" >
  <h2 class="Authors-title" id="a" th:text="${author.getAuthorName().charAt(0)}">
  </h2>
  <div class="Authors-letter">
    <div class="Authors-item"><a href="/authors/slug.html" th:text="${author.getAuthorName()}"></a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your getAuthorData() return Map<Character, List> where key is letter and value are authors starting with that letter

```
public List<Author> getAuthorData() {
    List<Author> authors = jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT id, authorName from authors ORDER BY 
    authorName", (ResultSet rs, int rowNum) -> {
        Author author = new Author();
        author.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
        author.setAuthorName(rs.getString("authorName"));
        return author;
    });
    return authors.stream()
       .collect(
          Collectors.groupingBy(
             author -> author.getAuthorName().charAt(0)
          )
       );
}
```

In html you can iterate through map entries like here: [How to loop through Map in Thymeleaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23144358/how-to-loop-through-map-in-thymeleaf)
just notice that as a value you will have iterable array

Comment: Thank you so much! Streams here help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with collection selection as well.  Something like this for example:

```
<div class="Authors-block"
     th:each="letter : ${ {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'} }"
     th:with="authors=${authorsData.?[authorName.startsWith(#root.letter)]}"
     th:unless="${authorsData.?[authorName.startsWith(#root.letter)].empty}"
     >
  <h2 class="Authors-title" id="a" th:text="${letter}" />
  <div class="Authors-letter">
    <div class="Authors-item" th:each="author: ${authors}"><a href="/authors/slug.html" th:text="${author.getAuthorName()}"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I don't know if I'd recommend it.